# CakePHP: Proper way to delete a record securely

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have this in my Controller.

```
public function delete($id) {
    if($this->request->is('get')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }

    $this->Memberlist->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Memberlist->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid list.'));
    }
    if ($this->Memberlist->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('List deleted.'), 'success');
        return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('List was not deleted.'), 'error');
    return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
}
```

My Model looks like this: (belongsTo)

```
<?php

class Memberlist extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Memberlist';
    public $belongsTo = array(
            'Account' => array(
            'className' => 'Account',
            'foreignKey' => 'account_id'
        )
    );
```

In one of my views, I have something like this:

```
echo $this->Form->postLink('Delete', 
                    array('action' => 'delete', $list['Memberlist']['id']),
                    array('class'=>'btn-mini btn', 'confirm' => 'Are you sure?'));
```

Which creates a HTML like this:

```
<form id="post_4fe15efc0d284" method="post" style="display:none;" name="post_4fe15efc0d284" action="/Grid/memberlists/delete/9">
<input type="hidden" value="POST" name="_method">
<input id="Token1627936788" type="hidden" value="8756f7ad21f3ab93dd6fb9a4861e3aed4496f3f9" name="data[_Token][key]">
<div style="display:none;">
</form>
<a class="btn-mini btn" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { document.post_4fe15efc0d284.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;" href="#">Delete</a>
```

The problem is that when I update the `ID` found in `action="/Grid/memberlists/delete/9"` using Firebug (or any developer tool), I can pretty much delete anything! Even from a different account. Even though I have the Security Component turned on.

What would be the proper way to do this? I am thinking of checking the `account_id` against the account_id of the currently logged-in user. But I am just curious if CakePHP has something out-of-the-box that fixes this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `beforeDelete` callback into your model, and query database and check if user is allowed to delete record and or is he owner.

Comment: I am new to CakePHP and found this answer to be very simple to implement. It also made a lot of sense to do this in the Model.

Answer (score 2):

To truly stop your users from being able to complete different actions, such as deleting things that do not belong to the user, you should use the [Auth Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html).

I'm assuming the Account model stores user data. You will need to follow the tutorial in the cookbook, but I highlighted how permission would be denied for deletion.

Your isAuthorized method would look something like this:

```
public function isAuthorized($account) {
    // The owner of a post can edit and delete it
    if (in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete'))) {
        $memberListId = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
        if ($this->MemberList->isOwnedBy($memberListId, $account['id'])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Default deny
    return false;
}
```

And this would go in the model:

```
public function isOwnedBy($memberList, $account) {
    return $this->field('id', array('id' => $memberList, 'account_id' => $account)) === $post;
}
```